# How to implement android espresso tests in the bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, android-espresso, bitbucket-pipelines, instrumented-test

I am implementing CI in my android project, but I am not able to put my Android espresso tests to run in the pipeline. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To better understand how to write a good question and get relevant answers, please read our [Welcome Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to and [How ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) articles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have devices to run espresso tests against. You can use services like a Firebase Test Lab and send your build to be tested there, and after the tests are finished, your results will be returned back to the bitbucket pipeline so you can continue with your CI process.

You can explore google cloud CLI, with which you can run bash scripts from your CI to send the build to the TestLab.